# Is pairwise multiple comparisons necessary with t/wilcox tests?

Tags: r, regression, anova, multiple-comparisons, ancova

I have two groups, young and old and within each group, I have four brain regions of interest (2 regions * 2 hemispheres).

I have run four separate t_tests in R looking at the difference in means, per ROI between young and old adults.

I would like to know the most appropriate way to adjust the p value, if even necessary (since it's only a comparison of two age groups per test).

I so far calculated a two way ANOVA with 2(age) x 4(ROI) to report as my adjust p value. But is this the most appropriate approach?